# Position absolute relate to the first element skipping the parent element?

Tags: css, sass

how to use position absolute for the first div skipping the parent div?

```
<ul>
<li>
<ul class="sub-menu">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How to use position absolute relate for the ul, not li?

Comment: Make your parent in position relative

Comment: I need to relate only for ul, not li

Comment: Are you missing the closing tags on both/all these elements?  Please fix the validity of the markup to get more pertinent answers.

Comment: .sub-menu li{ position:relative; } .sub-menu li ul { display:none; position:absolute; } .sub-menu li:hover ul{ display:block; }

Comment: I fixed. Check please

Answer (score 1):

Not realy sure what you want, but I suppose you mean something like this?:

```css
ul.menu,
ul.sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #1486e7;
}
ul.menu li {
  position: static;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
ul.menu > li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu clearfix">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2-1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2-2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2-3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4-1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4-2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4-3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> `position: absolute;`The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

That means that the `li`must be `position: static;`(which is the default value)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.sub-menu ul {position: absolute;}` for absolute positioning and

```
.sub-menu ul {position: relative;}
```

for relative positioning.

You set this in your css file

EDIT

```
<ul class ="sub-menu">
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and you can reference the class on the sub one to make it positinal in relation to the parent container

Comment: add .sub-menu and then ul. also the class is set in the opening ul bracket, not the closing

Comment: I think he is missing both closing tags

Comment: Is it `<ul>
<li></li>
<ul class="sub-menu"><li></li></ul></ul>`? hard to tell intent but I infer that from the OP's invalid markup...posted a note to the question to clarify.